# What's the time zone of Stack Overflow chat?

Tags: support, chat, timezone

[image: Snapshot of the chat image]

I made this screenshot a few minutes ago. My time zone is Central Europe, so my current time is 16:39 (CEST or UTC+2).

However, (based on the orange vertical bar) it seems that the Stack Overflow website thinks that my current time is around 13:30 (3 hours earlier).

What's going on here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything on Stack Exchange is based on UTC time.

In your screenshot where it says `12:00`, the bar for `12:00` is above the `1` in `12:00`, so the time it is indicating as current is `14:30`, which matches up with it being `16:30` at UTC+2.

Comment: Now I know `:)`

Comment: Huh. I would have assumed that the times were centered with respect to the bar (_i.e._ bar above the colons) if you'd asked me this out of the blue. Not that that really matters in any way whatsoever.

Comment: @PopularDemand, look at it in terms of the very left of the graph at 0:00.

Comment: The live chat room is an exception; there (and only there) we show the user's local time.

Comment: sure, that'd be reasonable if I actually _thought_ about it. But first-glance, gut-reaction, immediate/instinctive reaction? "Things are centered." (Again, not that that really matters in any way whatsoever.)